# Set arithmetic for slices/ranges

Tags: python

Is there set arithmetic for slices/ranges in Python?

I want to be able to perform things like

```
for i in range(0,10)-range(3,5):
    print(i)

0,1,2,5,6,7,8,9
```

Comment: You can use `numpy array` to solve this. `aa=np.arange(10);
bb=np.concatenate((np.array(aa[aa<3]),np.array(aa[aa>4])))`

Comment: `bb=array([0,1,2,5,6,7,8,9])` this would be the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've found it:

```
>>> sorted(set(range(0,10))-set(range(3,5)))
{0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
```

Comment: But `set` is an unordered collection. You wouldn't get `{0,1,2,5,6,7,8,9}` everytime.

Comment: @Ch3steR You're right. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `continue` to skip those values:

```
for i in range(10):
    if i in range(3,5):
        continue
    print(i)
```

Or as @Chris_Rands suggested in comments:

```
 for i in range(10):
    if i not in range(3,5):
        print(i)
```

Comment: `if i not in range(3,5): print(i)` -- on python 3 this is very efficient because of the way `in` is implemented for range objects

Comment: We can use `numpy arrays`. `a=np.arange(10); b=np.arange(3,5);a=np.delete(a,b)`

Comment: Output would be `array([0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])`